# awk with date convert from unix time to date

Tags: date, unix, awk

How to convert Epoch time to date ( mac os) and print both columns.

```
1556453126 20 
1567954567 30 
1567988161 25 
1566992153 40
```

`awk -F';' -v OFS=';'  '$1 {cmd="date -d \""$1"\" +%s"; cmd | getline $1; close(cmd)} 1' t.log`

strftime not working in mac os

expected:

```
2019-03-01 21:00 20
2019-03-02 20:50 30
2019-01-21 21:30 25
2019-08-01 21:30 40
```

Any readable date format will be OK

Comment: Why do you have  `-F';' -v OFS=';' ` when your sample only has space a field separator?

Comment: Install gawk...

Answer (score 0):

When you have a small amount of data, the answer of [James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918510/8344060) is quick and good enough.

Below I present several solutions which you can use depending on which awk you use:

**Gnu awk:** One of the various extensions of `gawk` are Time-functions. The two useful time-functions for this problem are `mktime` and `strftime`:

> - **`strftime(format,timestamp,[utc-flag])`**: This converts an epoch-time `timestamp` into a formatted string (same formatting as the `date` command). You can use the `utc-flag` the indicate that the returned time should be in UTC or in the local time-zone.
>
> More info in the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)

```
$ awk '{$1=strftime("%F %R",$1)}1' data.txt
```

**POSIX awk:** if you do not have GNU awk, but any other awk, you cannot use those time-functions as they are GNU awk specific. It is, however, possible to implement them:

```
awk '

# Algorithm from "Astronomical Algorithms" By J.Meeus
function strftime_posix(epoch, JD,yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM,SS,A,B,C,D,E ) {
    if (epoch < 0 ) return "0000 00 00 00 00 00.000000"
    JD=epoch; SS=JD%60; JD-=SS; JD/=60; MM=JD%60;
    JD-=MM; JD/=60; HH=JD%24; JD-=HH; JD/=24;
    JD+=2440588
    A=int((JD - 1867216.25)/(36524.25))
    A=JD+1+A-int(A/4)
    B=A+1524; C=int((B-122.1)/365.25); D=int(365.25*C); E=int((B-D)/30.6001)
    dd=B-D-int(30.6001*E)
    mm = E < 14 ? E-1 : E - 13
    yyyy=mm>2?C-4716:C-4715
    return sprintf("%0.4d-%0.2d-%0.2d %0.2d:%0.2d",yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM)
}

{ $1 = strftime_posix($1) }1' data.txt
```

Be aware that this will not correct for your timezone and will return the value in UTC.